# Making a img within a div stretch its width to the whole screen

Tags: css

I'm trying to replicate the image usage you see here: https://medium.com/backchannel/the-gentleman-who-made-scholar-d71289d9a82d

My problem is I'm using Wordpress and I can't split the content in different DIVs as they did at Medium.com

So, I'd need a method to make an image which is within a, let's say, 700px wide DIV extend the whole screen width.

Here's a code example:

The HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="main">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam officia reprehenderit eligendi eaque facere vitae, illum amet quasi dolores neque optio tenetur dignissimos, alias nulla repudiandae iste ex numquam atque.
            </p>


            <img class="full" src='1.jpg' />

            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam officia reprehenderit eligendi eaque facere vitae, illum amet quasi dolores neque optio tenetur dignissimos, alias nulla repudiandae iste ex numquam atque.
            </p>
        </div>                
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: beige;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}


.main {
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #555555;
}

.full {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Is there a way I can make that image stretch its width to the whole screen without taking it out of that DIV's text flow?

I tried many things and achieved nothing so far :(

Comment: @Benjamin max-width will not be aware of the window size, only its parent. So that is not a complete solution

Answer (score 1):

If you're only catering for modern browsers, you can use [the `vw` unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-values-20110906/#vw-unit):

> **vw unit** Equal to 1/100th of the width of the initial containing block.

```css
.full {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: just to note : IE 10+, Firefox 19+, Chrome 34+, Safari 7+, Android 4.4+, iOS 6+ supported VW

Comment: But in that way it will only spreand from the left border of the container. It won't go from the very left corner of the screen

Answer (score 0):

If you add  position:absolute in the main css class it will work.But i don't know whether it will work for your specific requirement

```
.main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #555555;
}
```

you can also achieve it by providing absolute position for image and top padding

```
.full {
    padding-top:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```